# Open in new tab JavaScript search

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my code to open a new tab in the browser rather than opening in the same tab, so I added `target="_blank"` after the `href`, but this doesn't work as I don't think it is being sent.

does anyone know how to fix this code so it works in a new window?

```
<script>
function changeText1(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + userInput ;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    window.location = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + userInput;
}
function changeText2(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://www.dogpile.com/serp?q=" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    window.location = "https://www.dogpile.com/serp?q=" + userInput;
}
function changeText3(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
    lnk.href = "https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + userInput;
    lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
    window.location = "https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + userInput;
}
</script>



<input type='text' id='userInput' value=' ' />
<input type='button' onclick='changeText1()' value='google'/>
<input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Dogpile'/> 
<input type='button' onclick='changeText3()' value='Yahoo'/>
<a href="" target="_blank" id=lnk </a> <br>
```

I tried adding target to this bit but, it didn't work.

```
<a href="" target="_blank" id=lnk </a> <br>
```

Comment: Your `a` tag isn't valid. It's missing a closing angle bracket and the value of the `id` attribute doesn't have quotes. It should look more like `<a href="" target="_blank" id="lnk"> </a>`

Comment: Hi i have changed it   <a href="" target="_blank" id="lnk"> </a>  but no change of behaviour :(

Comment: So what is your goal here? Your code is very confusing. I think you lack fundamental knowledge of HTML and JavaScript. You're setting the link in the `a` tag then just setting the current window's location to the same link. Your `a` tag is doing absolutely nothing. Either click on the `a` tag (manually or using the `.click()` method), or if you just want to do it all in JavaScript, get rid of it entirely and use [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Comment: Also, for future reference, "it doesn't work" is not a good description of behavior. Include what it's currently doing, what you're expecting it to do, any input you give it, what the output for said input is, and any error messages you may be encountering. Simply stating "it doesn't work" wastes the time of everyone because people reading have to figure out what the problem is themselves when you already know it.

Comment: Point 1 clearly i dont have a scooby doo, that is why im here I hope you feel powerful now you have put me down. 2 no error message. nothing no change no error nothing different it just opens the search in the same window . sorry i cant make it more exciting for you. sorry to waste your time im sure it is to valuable to be reading my reply.   i came here for a little help. i leave berated and sad  sorry

Comment: My goal isn't to put you down, my goal is to inform you why it's important to add detailed descriptions to your question of what is currently happening and what you expect to happen. Your question is framed in a way that makes it look like it's about the `a` tag, but that's not at all what it's about. The main confusion point for me is that you didn't specify the input. You have a link, and you have buttons, both of which can be clicked, but you didn't specify which one was being clicked. Your question is focused on the link, but you're not clicking the link. It took a bit to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `a` tag does not work as you are expecting. The `a` tag is used to encapsulate a link.
What would work for having the effect that you want is to refactor your functions to look like this:

```
function changeText1(){
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    var url = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + userInput ;
    
   window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
}
```

Using the `open` method of `window`

Comment: ok. thank you, i will have a play and see how that works. i have to admit i thought this would be just me putting stuff in the wrong order. but it seems a little more difficult. thank you. gives me something to look at and googe :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding "window.open(url, '_blank').focus();" in your function blocks.

```
lnk.href = "https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + userInput;
lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
window.open(lnk.href, '_blank').focus();
window.location = "https://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p=" + userInput;
```

Hard to say, try this and let me know if it works ! ??

Comment: This would both open a new tab and change the current tag because `window.location` is being set to the same link.

Comment: @MrZakaz Nice thank you. I will put it in and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the examples below: (a, button) tags

```js
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function () {
   window.open('https://www.google.com', "_blank");
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Link</a>
</br>
</br>
<button id="btn">button</button>
```